# JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Tags: javascript, user-interface, undefined

Why is it going into his if when the check is if its not undefined

```
 if (this.table !== undefined || this.table !== null) {
            this.table.destroy();
        }
```

Console error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Ive tried

```
if(this.table)
```

But no luck either

Comment: Because `undefined !== null` is true

Comment: try using `&&`.

Comment: tried using && but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if(this.table && typeof this.table.destroy === 'function'){ 
   this.table.destroy();
}
```

Comment: that didnt work either :/

Comment: This should be working. if not, please share more code like exactly where  are you using this code.